Advertising test to begin on December 3, 2024
We’ve been exploring the concept of using open auction to manage advertising on some Stack Exchange sites. Under this model, advertisers (who have been organized into categories based on their products) “bid” for an advertising spot. There is a floor price - a minimum price for the spot, and all bids must exceed that floor price.  This community will be testing the open auction experiment, beginning on December 3, 2024.  For more information or to provide feedback on the experiment, please refer to the post on Meta Stack Exchange.

(fifteen characters)

That's a lot of thumbs up, @Sycorax.

Gotta hit 15 characters somehow, now that spaces don’t count.
